# what does "ねぇぞ" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

what does "ねぇぞ" mean in this sentence?
 "出てねぇぞ"

Answer (score 0):

It's tough-sounding Tokyo dialect version of ない. 出てねえぞ = 出てないぞ = 出ていないぞ.